# Creating a PhoneGap iOS app with a pre-existing database

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova

I recently started working on an application that will serve as a Medicine Finder using PhoneGap (Version 2.8.0). In the past I created a web version of the tool which used jQuery Mobile and PHP to access a remote SQL database.

PhoneGap seemed like an attractive choice for turning the application into something that I could deploy to the iPhone/Android app stores but required that I re-write my previous web app in HTML5 & JavaScript. Because a majority of the people using the app would be on an iPad where internet connectivity is not always guaranteed, the plan for the app was to use a pre-populated local database.

Although the functionality of the app seemed very simple to implement, it appears that using pre-existing local db with PhoneGap is not so trivial. I have spent 15+ hours trying to find an easy way to do this with no success. I am aware that numerous phonegap+sqlite plugins exist on github but due to a lack of documentation and incompatibility with newer versions of PhoneGap I was unable to get them to work.

If there is anybody that has any experience with this I would really appreciate their input.

ALSO -  If necessary, what is the easiest tool for converting my .sql database (2 tables, one has around 360 entries the other has 20) into a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've upgraded one of my organisations project from phonegap 1.8 to phonegap 3.0 and used this plugin for SQLite handling

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

The installation guide is well written and if followed correctly, the plugin take minutes to get installed
[Guide](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin#installing)

Not sure about the converter from SQL to SQLite