# How to integrate a prepopulated sqlite database into a phonegap iPhone app

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, cordova

I want to integrate a prepopulated sqlite database into a phonegap iPhone app and I have trouble connecting to the database with javascript.

What are the necessary steps for that integration?

I use the Phonegap-SQLite plugin (https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin/). The unit tests run properly. (create a db on the fly, read/write from it), so the plugin works. But I can't access the prepopulated database.

The db is placed inside the Resources folder. It is listed under project options/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources

I try to allocate it in javascript as follows:

`var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "dbname.db"});`

It get a db object back, but not the filled db. Interestingly, when I do a new run in the simulator, the same database is used.

In the log window, I get the following messages:

> Finished load of:
>   file:///Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/33553FCA-3FFA-4BBB-9986-110721148F85/Appname.app/www/index.html
>
> 2013-07-09 18:39:14.977 Raumklima[49796:c07] Detected docs path:
>   /Users/dave/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/33553FCA-3FFA-4BBB-9986-110721148F85/Documents
>
> 2013-07-09 18:39:14.977 AppName[49796:c07] using db name:
>   /Users/usernam/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/33553FCA-3FFA-4BBB-9986-110721148F85/Documents/dbname.db

I use phone gap 2.5.0

Does anybody know where I have so search for a solution? What could be the problem? Or in general how this problem should be approached.

Similar questions have been asked on this platform, but no answers yet:

[Creating a PhoneGap iOS app with a pre-existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305203/creating-a-phonegap-ios-app-with-a-pre-existing-database)

[How to use a prepopulated SQLite database with PhoneGap / Cordova 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137555/how-to-use-a-prepopulated-sqlite-database-with-phonegap-cordova-2-0)

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673365/working-with-prepopulated-sqlite-database-in-phonegap-android/37857340#37857340

Answer (score 3):

The SQLitePlugin does not give you prepopulated databases as shipped. So what is currently happen is that you are opening the database in `Documents`, which don't already exist, so SQLite creates and opens an empty database.

If you want SQLitePlugin to populate the database from an existing SQLite DB in your Resources section, you need to do a bit of work to get there. This is what I did: (Replace the `open` method in `SQLPlugin.m`)

```
/* This is a hacked version which will copy the file from the Resources path
   if it does not exist in the Documents path or if it is newer. */

-(void)open: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbname = [self getDBPath:[options objectForKey:@"name"]];
    NSValue *dbPointer;

    if (dbname == NULL) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"You must specify database name"];
    }
    else {
        dbPointer = [openDBs objectForKey:dbname];
        if (dbPointer != NULL) {
            // NSLog(@"Reusing existing database connection");
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"Database opened"];
        }
        else {
            //NSLog(@"Opening %@", dbname );
            NSError *error;
            NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[options objectForKey:@"name"]];
            //NSLog(@"Date in app was %@", [[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp error:NULL] fileModificationDate] description]);
            //NSLog(@"Local date was %@", [[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:dbname error:NULL] fileModificationDate] description]);


            if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbname]) {
                BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbname error:&error] ;
                if (!success) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.",   [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                NSLog(@"Database didn't exist in %@, copying it from %@", dbname, databasePathFromApp);
            } else if ([[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp error:NULL] fileModificationDate] compare:[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:dbname error:NULL] fileModificationDate]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbname error:NULL];
                BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbname error:&error];
                if (!success) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.",   [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                NSLog(@"Database in app was newer, copying it from %@", databasePathFromApp);
                [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbname] setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: NULL];
            }
            const char *name = [dbname UTF8String];
            // NSLog(@"using db name: %@", dbname);
            sqlite3 *db;

            if (sqlite3_open(name, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
                pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Unable to open DB"];
                return;
            }
            else {
                // Extra for SQLCipher:
                // const char *key = [[options objectForKey:@"key"] UTF8String];
                // if(key != NULL) sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));

                // Attempt to read the SQLite master table (test for SQLCipher version):
                if(sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*)"SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                    dbPointer = [NSValue valueWithPointer:db];
                    [openDBs setObject: dbPointer forKey: dbname];
                    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"Database opened"];
                } else {
                    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Unable to encrypt DB"];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (sqlite3_threadsafe()) {
        NSLog(@"Good news: SQLite is thread safe!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Warning: SQLite is not thread safe.");
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId: command.callbackId];
}
```

Now if you ensure that you have added the databases to the Resources section of your project (and also added them to "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases section of the target), databases will be copied from `Resources` to `Documents` when necessary. This will return a handle to the writable database in the Documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code from http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html, modified the last, adding a check if sqlite db already exists.

```
void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
    File CheckDirectory;
    CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
    if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
    { 
        CheckDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    File f = new File(folder+file);
    if(!f.exists()) {       
    InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
    in.close(); out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this problem for a long time - the issue is you want to import a pre-populated database - which there are not alot of easy solutions for.  I found the best - and currently just about the ONLY - solution to be LiteHelpers  CORDOVA-SQLITE-EXT (https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)

I have added this in to my app and it is working well.  I had to switch away from PhoneGap though - and use CORDOVA - but it is working for me.